# Unity/C# - JSON array without key and value pair returns null

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Here is an example of my JSON data, it is automatically generated in a Python code.

```
{
  "class_labels":[
    [
      [
        0.0,
        0.0,
        1.0,
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "translations":[
    [
      [
        1.0,
        2.0,
        3.0,
      ],
      [
        3.0,
        2.0,
        1.0,
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "scales":[
    [
      [
        1.0,
        2.0,
        3.0,
      ],
      [
        3.0,
        2.0,
        1.0,
      ],
      [
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "angles":[
    [
      [
        0.0,
      ],
      [
        0.0,
      ],
      [
        5.0,
      ]
    ]
  ],
```

It is supposed to be valid JSON but I can only get 0 where I try to Debug.Log() all of the items from the JSON. When I tried to Debug.Log() the entire JSON text (my pyOutput file), everything did show up.

Since this is the first time I have seen a JSON structure like this, I don't know how to access each array.

This is my Unity C# code, `int` was corrected and edited into `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>>`.

```
public TextAsset pyOutput;
    public static class JSONReader
    {
        public static ModelInfo GetJSON(TextAsset pyOutput)
        {
            ModelInfo aModelInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<ModelInfo>(pyOutput.text);
            return aModelInfo;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(JSONReader.GetJSON(pyOutput));
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class ModelInfo
    {
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>> class_labels;
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>> translations;
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>> sizes;
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>> angles;
    }
```

The code is now returning null instead of 0, is it actually outputting the array but I'm just printing it wrongly to console?

Answer (score 1):

Here you're expecting an `int`:

```
public int class_labels;
```

But what JSON value represents that `int`?  This:

```
[
  [
    [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      1.0,
    ]
  ]
]
```

That's not an integer. That's an array of arrays of arrays of doubles.  Maybe you wanted this type instead?:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>> class_labels;
```

If the property *should be* a single integer value (or should be anything other than what it currently is) then that would need to be corrected at the source of the data. But the data you have now is simply not an integer.

Comment: class_labels are supposed to be integers (0,0 and 1.0 outputs only), but other values are doubles. Thank you for correcting me on that. However, it is now returning null when I try to print it to console with Debug.Log().

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing how I defined the json

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Params
    {
        public float[][][] class_labels = new float[0][][];
        public float[][][] translations = new float[0][][];
        public float[][][] sizes = new float[0][][];
        public float[][][] angles = new float[0][][];
    }

[System.Serializable]
    public class Info
    {
        public Params Params;
    }
```

Used [SimpleJSON](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON) to make deserialize/read the JSON

```
jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
        data = JSON.Parse(jsonString);
```

```
foreach (JSONNode pos in data["translations"]) // translation
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pos.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < pos[i].Count; k += 3)
                {
                    posX.Add(pos[i][k].AsFloat);
                }
            }
        }
```